# C++ program counting occurencces of numbers

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to write a C++ program that inputs five numbers between 1 and 100 and then the program outputs how many times each number occurs. Here's what I have so far but I keep getting an unresolved error message.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fillArray(int a[], int& size, int& numberUsed)
{
int i, hist[1000]; 

cout << "Enter 5 integers between 1 and 100" << endl;

for (i=0; i<size; i++)
{
cin >> a[i]; 
if(a[i] > 100)
{
i--; 
cout << "Num too big! 100 is max!" << endl;
}

}
numberUsed = i;


for (i=0; i<1000; i++)
hist[i] = 0;


for (i=0; i<numberUsed; i++)
{
hist[a[i]]++;
}

for (i=0; i<1000; i++)
if(hist[i])
cout << i << " occurs " << hist[i] << " times!" << endl;

}
```

The error message says the following "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol *main referenced in function _*_tmainCRTStartup"

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - you have no `main()` function.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm new at this so still learning. Can I put the whole code in the main function then?

Comment: You're probably going to want to write a `main()` function which does whatever initialisation might be needed and then calls your `fillArray()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add main() function to be able to link it.

Comment: I tried to add the main() function and it gave me this error message and won't let me compile it. Any ideas?
error C2601: 'fillArray' : local function definitions are illegal

Comment: `main()` needs to be a separate function - you can't nest functions in C or C++.

Comment: Alright I'll write a separate function, thanks for your help!